# Not generating image in a PDF using Thymeleaf + FOP

Tags: xml, thymeleaf, apache-fop

I wonder if someone could help me with this problem. I did google it for days but I did not find anything which could help me.
I have to create a PDF file using Thymeleaf and FOP.
I got all the PDF information from a XML file. In this, XML file I have some PNG images storaged in base64 which have to be shown in the PDF file.

```
<myXML:Attachments>
        <myXML:Attached attachedID="FIRST_IMAGE">
            <myXML:ImageData>
                <myXML:Description>FIRST_IMAGE</myXML:Description>
                <myXML:Mime>image/png</myXML:Mime>
                <myXML:Data>iVBO...IIH=</myXML:Data>
            </myXML:ImageData>
        </myXML:Attached>
        <myXML:Attached attachedID="SECOND_IMAGE">
            <myXML:ImageData>
                <myXML:Description>SECOND_IMAGE</myXML:Description>
                <myXML:Mime>image/png</myXML:Mime>
                <myXML:Data>iVBO..CYII=</myXML:Data>
            </myXML:ImageData>
        </myXML:Attached>
</myXML:Attachments>
```

First of all, I checked that I could print an image in the PDF file. So, I harcoded the *Attached.ImageData.Data* information, in order to confirm that the image was fine. See the example below:

```
<fo:external-graphic 
    src="data:image/png;base64,iVBO...IIH"
/>
```

The example above worked fine. Secondly, I checked that the data parsed was exactly the same that the XML file:

```
<fo:table-row
th:each="img : ${Attachments.Attached}">
<fo:table-cell>     
    <fo:block th:text="${'data:' + img.ImageData.Mime + ';base64,'}+${{img.ImageData.Data}}">**srcImage**</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
```

In my PDF file I could see: *data:IMAGE_PNG;base64,iVBO...*
So, I feel positive that the parsed information is working fine.
Unfortunately, when I execute code with the example below, I got an error:

```
<fo:table-row
    th:each="img : ${Attachments.Attached}">
    <fo:table-cell> 
    <fo:block th:text="srcImage = ${'data:' + img.ImageData.Mime + ';base64,'}+${{img.ImageData.Data}}">
            <fo:external-graphic src="${srcImage}"/>
    </fo:block>
</fo:table-row>
```

> An error happened during template parsing (templateCaused by: 
>   org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could
>   not parse as expression:
>
> "srcImage = ${'data:' + img.ImageData.Mime +
>   ';base64,'}+${{img.ImageData.Data}}"      at
>   org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.StandardExpressionParser.parseExpression(StandardExpressionParser.java:131)
>     at
>   org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.StandardExpressionParser.parseExpression(StandardExpressionParser.java:62)
>     at
>   org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.StandardExpressionParser.parseExpression(StandardExpressionParser.java:44)
>     at
>   org.thymeleaf.engine.EngineEventUtils.parseAttributeExpression(EngineEventUtils.java:220)
>     at
>   org.thymeleaf.engine.EngineEventUtils.computeAttributeExpression(EngineEventUtils.java:207)
>     at
>   org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.java:67)
>     at
>   org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74)
>     at
>   org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95)
>     at
>   org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633)
>     at
>   org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1314)
>     at
>   org.thymeleaf.engine.OpenElementTag.beHandled(OpenElementTag.java:205)

I am a really begginer with Thymeleaf and FOP. I really appreciate if you could help me with this issue.

Thank you for your consideration.